# Thread won't run in background?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

When I call `my_batch.run_jobs()`, my thread does not run in the background. Instead, it runs synchronously by waiting for the method to finish running.

For context, I am calling this method from within a `.py` file, and the method is within a class. When I run the same functions outside of this file/class, it runs in the background just fine.

```py
# package_name/module_name.py


class BaseModel(Model):
    class Meta:
        database = get_db()


class Batch(BaseModel):

    def run_jobs():
        
        def sleeper():
            sleep(999)
        
        t = threading.Thread(target=sleeper)
        #t.daemon = True #tried with/ without
        t.start()
```

for example

```py
my_batch = Batch()
my_batch.run_jobs()
#doesn't print until line above finishes
print("in progress")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated your code for testing. It seems to run as expected.

```
import time, threading

class BaseModel(): pass
#    class Meta:
#        database = get_db()

class Batch(BaseModel):

    def run_jobs(self):
        
        def sleeper(): # runs in background thread
            for t in range(10):
               print('<sleeper>', t)
               time.sleep(.9)
        
        t = threading.Thread(target=sleeper)
        t.start()
        
        # this runs same time as background thread (sleeper)
        for t in range(10):
           print('<rj>', t)
           time.sleep(.8)
                
mybatch = Batch()
mybatch.run_jobs()  # runs in main thread

# this loop runs after run_jobs completes
for t in range(5):
   print('<main>', t)
   time.sleep(1)
```

Output

```
<sleeper> 0
<rj> 0
<rj> 1
<sleeper> 1
<rj> 2
<sleeper> 2
<rj> 3
<sleeper> 3
<rj> 4
<sleeper> 4
<rj> 5
<sleeper> 5
<rj> 6
<sleeper> 6
<rj> 7
<sleeper> 7
<rj> 8
<rj> 9
<sleeper> 8
<main> 0
<sleeper> 9
<main> 1
<main> 2
<main> 3
<main> 4
```

--- Update ---

Here is the same code split into modules:

-- mike.py

```
import time, threading

class BaseModel(): pass
#    class Meta:
#        database = get_db()

class Batch(BaseModel):

    def run_jobs(self):
        
        def sleeper(): # runs in background thread
            for t in range(10):
               print('<sleeper>', t)
               time.sleep(.9)
        
        t = threading.Thread(target=sleeper)
        t.start()
        
        # this runs same time as background thread (sleeper)
        for t in range(10):
           print('<rj>', t)
           time.sleep(.8)
```

-- threadchk.py  (main script)

```
import mike
import time, threading
    
mybatch = mike.Batch()
mybatch.run_jobs()  # runs in main thread

# this loop runs after method completes
for t in range(5):
   print('<main>', t)
   time.sleep(1)
```

Output is the same as previous run

Comment: Thank you Mike. Would you mind putting the class in mike.py and doing `import mike` so it becomes `my_batch = mike.Batch()` to see if you still get the same thing?

Comment: Thank you. Now know that it is in fact supposed to work that way.